# Convert text file containing PowerShell Object Notations to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a text file (PsonObjects.txt) that contains PowerShell Object Notation as follows:

```
@{Computer=Dektop123; ServiceA=Running; ServiceB=Running; RunspaceId=1a-1b}
@{Computer=Dektop456; ServiceA=Stopped; ServiceB=Stopped; RunspaceId=2b-2c}
@{Computer=Laptop123; ServiceA=NotFound; ServiceB=Running; RunspaceId=3c-4c}
@{ServiceA=NotFound; Computer=Laptop456; ServiceB=Running; RunspaceId=4d-5d}
```

I would like to convert this Pson file into a Csv file, but have been unable to throughout my attempts.

The problem is sometimes an object's properties are in a different order than the previous object. Like the last line in the above example. Therefor simply converting the semicolon (';') to a comma (',') and removing the '@{}' characters does not produce a properly ordered Csv file.

Is there an easy way to convert this Pson (Powershell object notation) file into a CSV file?

Ive tried a few different methods, but I keep getting either the length of the string, or hashtable output (IsReadOnly, IsFixedSize, IsSychronized, keys, Values, SyncRoot, Count) in my CSV output file.

Non Working code:

```
$inputFile = PsonObjects.txt
$CsvFileName = CsvOutput.csv
foreach($line in (Get-Contnet $inputfile)){
  $newline = $line | convertFrom-StringData
  $newline | Export-CSV $CsvFileName -Append 
}
```

Any assistance or suggestions with this problem are appreciated.

Comment: As an aside: Your text file uses _for-display_ representations of custom objects, which aren't generally suited for _programmatic processing_. If possible, use a structured text format such as CSV to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConvertFrom-StringData` outputs an unsorted `Hashtable`, where the elements can be in any order, so it is of no use here.

Here is a possible solution, using the `-split` operator and a sorting step, using an *ordered* `Hashtable`:

```sh
$inputFile = 'PsonObjects.txt'
$csvFileName = 'CsvOutput.csv'

# The order of columns in the output CSV
$keyOrder = 'Computer','ServiceA','ServiceB','RunspaceId'

Get-Content $inputfile | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_.Trim('@{}')   # Remove unwanted characters from current line

    # First parse the current line into an unordered hashtable
    $ht = @{}
    foreach( $field in $line -split '; ' ) {
        $key, $value = $field -split '='
        $ht[ $key ] = $value
    }   

    # Using the order specified by $keyOrder, create an ordered hashtable
    $orderedHt = [ordered] @{}
    foreach( $key in $keyOrder ) {
        $orderedHt[ $key ] = $ht[ $key ]
    }

    [PSCustomObject] $orderedHt     # Convert hashtable to custom object

} | Export-Csv $csvFileName
```

**Output:**

```sh
"Computer","ServiceA","ServiceB","RunspaceId"
"Dektop123","Running","Running","1a-1b"
"Dektop456","Stopped","Stopped","2b-2c" 
"Laptop123","NotFound","Running","3c-4c"
"Laptop456","NotFound","Running","4d-5d"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative to [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72884491/15339544) using the [`Parser` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0):

```bash
$parse = Get-Content PsonObjects.txt -Raw
$ast   = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($parse, [ref] $null, [ref] $null)
$ast.EndBlock.Statements.PipelineElements.Expression | ForEach-Object {
    $out = [ordered]@{}
    foreach($pair in $_.KeyValuePairs) {
        $out[$pair.Item1.Extent.Text] = $pair.Item2.Extent.Text
    }
    [pscustomobject] $out
}
```

Code would be much simpler if the **Values** where quoted, since we would have the option to use [`.SafeGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast.safegetvalue?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-language-ast-safegetvalue), as you have them right now the parser is interpreting them as commands instead of strings.

```bash
$test = @'
@{Computer='Dektop123'; ServiceA='Running'; ServiceB='Running'; RunspaceId='1a-1b'}
@{Computer='Dektop456'; ServiceA='Stopped'; ServiceB='Stopped'; RunspaceId='2b-2c'}
'@

[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($test, [ref] $null, [ref] $null).
    EndBlock.Statements.PipelineElements.Expression.ForEach{ [pscustomobject] $_.SafeGetValue() }
```